# serialVersionUid of serialized object

Tags: android, file, object, serialization

I saved a file that contains a class. I forgot to put the `serialVersionUid`. Now, every change that I do in the class removes my files, how can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> removes my files.

No, it doesn't 'remove your files'. It causes an exception when deserializing.

The cure is to *put* a `serialVersionUID` declaration into the class. The exception gives you the expected value.

Comment: When i saved my class in the first time i didn't declare the serialversionUID, i made some changes in the class like add variables, now when i'm updating my app, i'm getting en error, what am i suppost to do?

Comment: I have already told you what to do. Don't just repeat your question. Read my answer.